# Encountered error when trying to access Integration Procedures in new sandbox

Tags: vlocity

I've had this error show up in a recently created sandbox - using Vlocity Public Sector package.

[image: Vlocity Error]

It only comes up when trying to access Integration Procedures - have had no issues getting into DataRaptors or Omniscripts.

Searching the error online provides very few results, none that are very helpful.

Has anyone encountered this error before, and what is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution from Vlocity knowlege article, copied and pasted some folks don't have the logins. (and don't ask me to explain why the fix works, take it up with Vlocity developers). Hope it helps people who affected.

Article Number
000003569

Applicable Versions
Available in All Versions

Description
This DML currently not allowed message is due to a missing document file that OmniScript is attempting to load. Replacing the file will correct this error.

(This issue may also affect the loading of Integration Procedures.)
Resolution
To correct the error, follow these steps:
Go to Documents.
In the Document folders section, click the dropdown list and select 'Vlocity Document Uploads."
Click New Document.
Name and Unique Name = VlocityLogoDocumentUploads.
Attach the file that is attached to this article (or you can use any images, jpg or png files) and click Save.

Comment: Why is this relevant to the question's error message regarding DML not currently allowed? It'd be great to explain why this "fix" works based on the question being asked

Comment: You can refer to the knowledge article from Vlocity to save everytime time: https://success.vlocity.com/s/article/Error-DML-currently-not-allowed-in-OmniScript-Designer

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/372531/edit) your answer to 1) add the link you posted in the above comment *(you should generally edit a post to add that sort of additional information, rather than putting/leaving it in a comment where it could be easily missed)* & 2) elaborate on your answer enough to give an overview of how that fixes the issue, so people don't have to click the link to find out. *(FYI, when I clicked the link I was asked to log in - that's not helpful.)* As Kris mentioned, the "why" is important here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issue is that the developers need to fix the offending code. You can't fix this on your own.

The problem is that the code is attempting to perform a database operation (DML) while the database is in a "read-only" section of code. This can happen in a constructor, a getter, a `@ReadOnly` method or `readOnly` page, a component without `allowDML` enabled, or an `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` method.

My initial educated guess is that this is an error in a Visualforce page from a recent modification they may have made to the package. The only way to fix this is for a developer to go in and change the code so it no longer attempts to perform a DML operation in a read-only execution state. Their support team should have a process to get this fixed.